# jquery auto loading map from mysql

Tags: mysql, dictionary

I have image map that can I move, but this map will be so big, so I would like to load it dynamically like google maps or maps in browser games.
But i dont know how does it work, can you help me?
I need just word solution not code

Thanks

Edit: i have 1 idea, maybe try to make div with width and heigth about 20000px and while moving the map add there new divs, but if is it this good idea how can i control loading new divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your image in tiles. Then add them to your scrolling area as they come into the viewable area, and remove them as they go outside it. This scrolling area could be as simple as a div with a certain size and `overflow:scroll;`, with a child div much larger.

Comment: "Then add them to your scrolling area as they come into the viewable area, and remove them as they go outside it" how control it?

Comment: Check how far the inner div is scrolled, and divide it by the size of your tile. Then you know which tile to pick.